# Objects identification and their relationships

Tags: oop, uml

I'm trying to do my OOP homework, but I am having problems with the identification of objects. The problem says:

> A country has provinces, a capital city, limit with other countries
>   and is located on a continent. The provinces of a country bordering
>   other provinces of the same country and may limit with other
>   countries. The provinces have cities and one of them is its capital.

I think the objects are:

- **Continent**
- **Country**
- **Province**
- **City**

But all these objects **are territories**, and a city can be capital or not. So, in this case:

- **Territory**
- **Continent** (extends **Territory**)
- **Country** (extends **Territory**)
- **Province** (extends **Territory**)
- **City** (extends **Territory**)
- **CapitalCity** (extends **City**)
- **CommonCity** (extends **City**)

So,

A **Contienent** has a collection of **Country**.
A **Country** has a collection of **Province** and a **CapitalCity**.
A **Province** has a collection of **City** and a **CapitalCity**.

This is well done or should I ignore the **Territory**, **CapitalCity** and **CommonCity**?

Comment: All those are objects. Maybe you're asking for the class model (which you began to sketch)?

Comment: It's impossible to do good OO modeling without knowing behaviors. It's not because we say that "A country has Provinces" that Country necessary has a collection of Province objects.

Comment: @ThomasKilian: All what are objects?

Comment: @plalx: what evidence do you have that one cannot do good OO modeling without knowing behaviors? The books I've read add behaviors later, which matches my experience.

Comment: Tomas, I suggest you sketch the association-end properties, as I recommend in another answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29462410/2596664

Comment: @JimL. Because behaviors and invariants is what shapes the objects. For instance, if I say that we may add `Comment`s to a `Post`. There are no invariants to enforce, so there's no reason for `Post` to hold a collection of `Comment` objects. Large clusters comes at great cost in real systems since they limit concurrency and scalability. On the other hand, if we had an invariant stating than the same `Author` may not comment twice on the same `Post`, then we have an invariant which we probably wish to enforce strongly.

Comment: In order to do so, we must bring both, `Post` and it's `Comment` in a single object cluster (boundary). That's just a simple example, but behaviors is the essence of OO design. Without behaviors you are just modeling data containers.

Comment: @plalx: There are different kinds of OO models for different concerns. One should start with a solid understanding of the important concepts and properties in a problem domain, which can take the form of a perfectly good OO model. Behaviors augment an OO model, making the model more complete for the purpose of building a given system. The result is still an OO model, just for a different concern. The goodness of a model is measured by fitness for purpose, not level of detail. Perhaps some good OO models are merely insufficiently elaborated for your purposes.

Comment: @JimL. I get your point, but modeling without behaviors is hardly an OO modeling activity. It's only modeling data structures. You might want to read this http://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/AnemicDomainModel.html

Comment: @JimL. The title asks for __object__ identification, but I suspect it should be the __class__ model which is being searched for.

Comment: @plalx: I am in full agreement with Martin Fowler: an anemic model in an OOPL is certainly an anti pattern. However, there is more OO work to be done in an enterprise than programming in an OOPL.