# UML for a simple board game review

Tags: uml, game-engine

I'm starting to develop a board game in C++ using OpenGL.
Before starting, I want to draw the UML diagram, as shown bellow.

The game has:

- A board that contains a desktop, a footer and the points of both players to show.
- Pieces to put on the board
- Followers (soldiers)
- Mouse events
- A set of rules that the players must obay in order to play

Something like The Risk, of Monopoly, etc

I'm not an expert in UML, so by looking at what I've written so far, **do you think the UML (arrows and relations) is accurate with the description?**

**What would you change, and why?**

[image: UML for the game]

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29461613/game-class-diagram/29462410#29462410 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to tell without knowing the game (use case). Generally you seem to over-use aggregation. Also I miss the basic properties/methods of the single classes. Those are general observations.

Some detail observations:

- The model does not differentiate between the game and the technology.
- What for it this `Object`? It seems rather pointless. You'd better be off designing the game logic first: what are those `Pieces` and what can they do? Think of a better name (my dictionary suggests Token, Meeple, PlayingPiece). Things are only what their name is!
- What are the `Rules`? I don't see any rule class at all.
- Create a 2nd diagram/layer where you can concentrate on technology in a later stage.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback:) I will try to improve it!